# Dynamic size of UIImageView inside UITableViewCell

Tags: swift, uitableview, swift3, uiimageview, constraints

I have a `UIImageView` defined in Main.storyboard, inside a `UITableViewCell` and I want it to change its width according to the screen size, and I want it to change height so its Aspect Ratio is the same as of the `UIImage`.

(For example news feed in FB app – images have always the same width, but different height according to their original aspect ratio).

I tried following options (based on other SO questions):

1. Setting Trailing, Leading, Bottom, Top constraints (all = 8)

   - (My cells expand their heights according to their content)
   - One `UIImageView` in `UITableView` seems to have the correct size
   - Other images have massive white space above and below the image
   - This white space seems to increase with scrolling
2. The same as above, plus `UIImageView.frame`

   - The most common advice was probably to change `UIImageView.frame = CGRect(...)`
   - Image View ignored those instructions and the size was still the same for all Image Views in all cells OR
   - Image View put some random heights there and had massive white space below the images
3. This helped: [How do i scale an image correctly with fixed width and auto layout?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/20576251/how-do-i-scale-an-image-correctly-with-fixed-width-and-auto-layout)

   ```
   let aRatio = (image?.size.width)! / (image?.size.height)!
   cell.myImageView?.contentMode = .scaleAspectFit
   let aRatioConstraint = NSLayoutConstraint(item: cell.myImageView, 
                                                   attribute:  NSLayoutAttribute.width, 
                                                   relatedBy: NSLayoutRelation.equal, 
                                                   toItem: cell.myImageView,
                                                   attribute: NSLayoutAttribute.height, 
                                                   multiplier: aRatio, 
                                                   constant: 0.0)
   cell.myImageView?.addConstraint(aRatioConstraint)
   ```

   - It works for a lot of images, but some still have white spaces up and down + portraits ("tall" pictures) have white spaces left and right.
   - Both cases can be solved by vigorously calling `tableView.reloadData()` until the correct size appears.
   - Scrolling through tableView messes everything up.

I tried many many more approaches (eg. adding height constraints instead of manipulating frame directly), but everything comes down to two things: weird white spaces and/or problem when scrolling, thus necessity to trigger `tableView.reloadData()` again and again for the desired result.

So, what is the recommended approach?

*OT: This behaviour (of undesired changing of contents and properties) is rather common and I experienced it also while coloring Pins (annotation marks in maps). When I moved the map so the pins were not visible on the screen and moved back, the pins switched colors (wtf). Maybe there is a more general approach for dealing with all these similar things?*

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The problem was that I was downloading the images from the web when the cells were being initiated and again when they were being reused.

Donwloading the cells content only once and storing them solved the problem.

Another way could be calculating the cell content height and defining them at `heightForRowAt indexPath`.